# Python threading isAlive weird result

Tags: python, multithreading

I am playing around with Python threading recently with Python 2.7.5~2.7.6
I've just noticed a weird situation, (well, maybe not actually but it is really weird to me)

Here is the code I was running

First I define a class that extends threading like this:

```
class worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(worker, self).__init__(name='a_name')
    def run(self):
        print 'running'
        time.sleep(5)
        print 'exiting'
```

then I started in the Main Thread of the python program

```
workers = []
_worker = worker()
workers.append(_worker)
_worker.start()
is_running = _worker.is_alive()
while is_running:
    for _worker in workers:
        print 'checking...'
        print _worker.ident, _worker.is_alive()
        if not _worker.is_alive():
            _worker = worker()
            _worker.start()
            print 'restarting...'
            print _worker.ident, _worker.is_alive()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The situation I've met is that when I run this code, before the first time the worker thread ends, everything goes perfectly. However, when I try to restart the ended thread, things go weird, as the last check before sleep yields True on is_alive, but right after that, the first check within the for loop gives False!

Below is the output from terminal:

```
running...checking...
4319211520 True

checking...
4319211520 True
checking...
4319211520 True
exiting...
checking...
4319211520 False
running...
restarting...
4319211520 True
checking...
4319211520 False
running...
restarting...
4325380096 True
```

So my main question is why the check fails every time I restart a thread?

Comment: `is_running = _worker.is_alive()` followed by `while is_running:` is wrong... the variable `is_running` will only be evaluated once, before you start the loop. It looks like you intend it to be checked on each iteration of the loop, so code should be `while _worker.is_alive():`

Answer (score 2):

When you restart a worker, you need to update `workers`. Assigning to `_worker` won't do that: `workers` will still contain the old thread and you'll keep checking that old thread over and over again.

Comment: But the thread's ID or the number from ``ident'' attribute has changed over time, so I assumed workers has updated also. Why is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, in order to check whether the workers list is updated or not, I tried one time to set _worker to None, then I can see exceptions.